# how to connect BLE devices using native BT app on Android platform

Tags: android, android-ndk, bluetooth-lowenergy

if we could develop NDK native Bluetooth app（based on C++） on Android platform to get full access(scan/pair/connect) to other Bluetooth devices(BLE or BR/EDR devices)?  and all BT operations without any JAVA APIs.
The reason of I not use the BT java app APIs is to reduce the latency and product design.

Comment: As far as I know the only public API is the java API. If you try to use some internal API you will probably get compatibility issues.

Comment: we could see some native BT test app in Android ./system/bt/test/ path;which allows access to the Bluetooth HAL API through ASCII command. And the app is mutually exclisive with the Java based Bluetooth.apk .